# Test for standard streams piping failed

Tags: c, stream, pipe, file-descriptor

After creating a [function to grab stdin, stdout & stderr](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71793/function-to-grab-stdin-stdout-stderr-of-a-child-process), I wanted to test it ..

Here is the test code:

```
int fd[3];
char *buf = calloc(200, sizeof(char));
FILE *stream;
pid_t pid;

pid = opencmd(fd, "/bin/echo", (char *[]){"/bin/echo", "hello!"});

stream = fdopen(fd[2], "r");
while (fgets(buf, 200, stream) != NULL)
    printf("stderr: %s\n", buf);
fclose(stream);

stream = fdopen(fd[1], "r");
while (fgets(buf, 200, stream) != NULL)
    printf("stdout: %s\n", buf);
fclose(stream);

free(buf);
closecmd(pid, fd);
```

This does not manage to work as intended. I spent an hour debugging and could not manage to trace the problem, but as far as I managed to go, I realized that using `fdopen` to start using the descriptors' streams does not work (for some reason), but using functions that work directly with file descriptors (such as `write(2)` & `read(2)`) works fine.

What might be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `opencmd()`.  As far as I can tell, it is not standardized anywhere, so who knows what it may do?  As for `fdopen()`, if it returns non-NULL then you should expect to be able to read use the stream it provides.  Otherwise, `errno` will be set to indicate the nature of the failure.  If you want more specific analysis then it would help to give us a more specific explanation of "does not work".

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `opencmd()` is a utility function I created to automate my usual piping work (click on the link to see what it does). As for analysis, the test code does not read from the file descriptor correctly.

Comment: this excerpt: (char *[]){"/bin/echo", "hello!"}); is missing the final NULL parameter

Comment: @user3629249: Thank you! The code actually **works** now. I always miss that parameter ..

Answer (score 0):

this excerpt: (char *[]){"/bin/echo", "hello!"}); is missing the final NULL parameter – user3629249